# Updating Client Application using DCR endpoint not working in WSO2 IS V6?

Tags: curl, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am using WSO2 IS V6.1 and I can create a client application using the DCR endpoint if I run the following cURL command.

```
curl -k -X POST -H "Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"client_name": "application1","grant_types": ["password"],"ext_param_client_id":"provided_client_id0002","ext_param_client_secret":"provided_client_secret0002" }' "https://localhost:9443/api/identity/oauth2/dcr/v1.1/register"
```

But, when I try to update the client application using the following cURL command as shown in the documentation[1],

```
curl -k -X PUT -H "Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "redirect_uris":["https://client.example.org/callback"],"client_name":"application1","grant_types": ["password","authorization_code"] }' "https://localhost:9443/api/identity/oauth2/dcr/v1.1/register"
```

I can see the following warning message in the `wso2carbon.log` file and when I check the SP using the management console, it has not been updated.

```
[2024-02-13 11:14:53,129] [b1c1ef57-007d-4668-a261-65ef33cb3b14]  WARN {org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.WebApplicationExceptionMapper} - javax.ws.rs.ClientErrorException: HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.SpecExceptions.toHttpException(SpecExceptions.java:117)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.ExceptionUtils.toHttpException(ExceptionUtils.java:168)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.findTargetMethod(JAXRSUtils.java:673)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.processRequest(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:182)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.handleMessage(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:79)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:265)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:225)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:304)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPut(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:234)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:558)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:481)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:130)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:119)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.OrganizationContextRewriteValve.invoke(OrganizationContextRewriteValve.java:115)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.SameSiteCookieValve.invoke(SameSiteCookieValve.java:38)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.cors.valve.CORSValve.invoke(CORSValve.java:83)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:154)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:142)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:114)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:49)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:152)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:673)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:63)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestEncodingValve.invoke(RequestEncodingValve.java:49)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestCorrelationIdValve.invoke(RequestCorrelationIdValve.java:137)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:389)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:926)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1791)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

It seems the PUT method is not implemented for updating a client application. Is there another way to update the client application using the DCR endpoint? If so, what is the cURL command for that?

**Note:**

It seems the cURL command given in the documentation is incorrect and it should be,

```
curl -k -X PUT -H "Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "redirect_uris":["https://client.example.org/callback"],"client_name":"application1","grant_types": ["password","authorization_code"] }' "https://localhost:9443/api/identity/oauth2/dcr/v1.1/register/provided_client_id0002"
```

The client ID should be specified in the URL `https://localhost:9443/api/identity/oauth2/dcr/v1.1/register/<client_id>`

1. https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/guides/access-delegation/oauth-dynamic-client-registration/#update-an-oauth-application

Answer (score 1):

During the application creation we have enabled only the password grant type but in the update call we're trying to add `redirect_uris` even though the authorization_code/implicit grant is not enabled. That's why the error is getting thrown.

To update the SP with redirect URL, please try the below command

```
curl -k -X PUT -H "Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "client_name": "application_1", "grant_types": ["authorization_code","password","implicit"], "redirect_uris":["https://client.example.org/callback"] }' "https://localhost:9443/api/identity/oauth2/dcr/v1.1/register/provided_client_id0002"
```